# XML class for parse

Tags: c#, .net, xml, parsing, serialization

I have class model for XML structure, where i want parse xml into it. 
I used XSD generator. Everything will be fine, but two things don't work.

First: I have something like that in xml:

```
<protocol>

<!-- an error message which may appear from both sides as a response anytime.-->
<message type="error">
some string
</message>

...
</protocol>
```

My class set which i got from xsd generator doesn't have any field in my message class where i can get that some string. What attribute i have to assign to field which i create in that class: (string message) for getting this value?

Second: I have something like that in xml:

```
<message type="gameState">
<gameId id="zxcc"/>
<!-- one tag of the two below appears in message -->
<nextPlayer nick="asdd"/>
<gameOver>
<!-- this tag appears repeatedly for all the players -->
<player nick="zxc" result="winner"/>
</gameOver>
<!-- this tag will always appear. Not read by the server.-->
<gameState>
</gameState>
</message>
```

And generator create in message class this for gameOver:

```
/// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute("gameOver", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("player", typeof(player), IsNullable=false)]
    public player[][] gameOver {
        get {
            return this.gameOverField;
        }
        set {
            this.gameOverField = value;
        }
    }
```

And i get exception:

```
Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'player[]' to 'player'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'player' to 'player[]'
```

player is class defined by generator, it works in other attributes. I find that this fragment xml is only complex node where i have 3 degree.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I find solution for my first problem.

I had to add a

```
[XmlText]
public string Value { get; set; }
```

to my Message class for serialize into it text within `<message></message>` but i can't find solution for second problem. Any thoughts?